# How can I handle multiple server MongoDB with Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am using Morphia.
And now I have two mongoDB server:
'mongodb://user:password@server1.com:3800,server2.com:3717/testDb?replicaSet=mgset-502725001'

How can I connect both server by Morphia?

I can only connet one server right now:

```java
@Bean(name = "mongoClient")
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        List<MongoCredential> credentialsList = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
        MongoCredential credentia = MongoCredential.createCredential(
                mongoDbUserName, mongoDbDatabase, mongoDbPassword.toCharArray());
        credentialsList.add(credentia);
        MongoClientOptions clientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .maxConnectionIdleTime(6000 * 5)
                .maxConnectionLifeTime(0)
                .build();

        // only one server here
        ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress("server1.com", 3800);
        return new MongoClient(addr, credentialsList, clientOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can handle like this:

```java
        MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + mongoDbUserName + ":" +
                mongoDbPassword + "@" + mongoDbHost + ":" + mongoDbPort + "/" + mongoDbDatabase);
        return new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
```